# How to write query WHERE with IN Clause in Silverstripe 4

Tags: php, mysql, silverstripe

How to write a below query in SilverStripe to get specific column data.

```
SELECT Title FROM Devmac_Object_ProductType WHERE ID IN ($strProductListID)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Devmac_Object_ProductType` is the table representing the `Devmac\Object\ProductType` DataObject, and `$strProductListID` is a flat array of IDs:

```php
use Devmac\Object\ProductType;

$strProductListID = [1,2,7];

$filteredProductTitles = ProductType::get()->filter('ID', $strProductListID)->column('Title');
```

You can also get a map of IDs to Titles using `map('ID', 'Title')`:

```php
$filteredProductTitles = ProductType::get()->filter('ID', $strProductListID)->map('ID', 'Title');
```

This will return a `Map`, which can be converted to an associative array using `->toArray()`.

See the developer documentation on [Managing Lists](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/model/lists/).

Comment: @amit-gajare You might also be interested in watching the lessons at https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/v4/ . There everything how to work with the ORM and databases is explained in depth.